# Trying to understand this t-sql if statement

Tags: t-sql, if-statement

I am working with someone else's code, and I just want to understand with this statement really means...

```
IF ((@TablesToCheck & 1) <> 0) {
   *Some bit of code*
}
```

@TablesToCheck is an int taken in via parameter. I get that this is checking if something is not 0, but I am not sure I understand what the *(@TablesToCheck & 1)* is. Is it just in-case @TablesToCheck is null?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a bitwise AND.  It's checking to see if the low order bit in @TablesToCheck is set to 1

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Robert Harvey, Thank you! So if I understand, this is checking if the variable TablesToCheck is equal to 1, but bitwise? Would the = sign work here to? or is there a reason for not using =?

Comment: It's checking to see if bit 0 (the Least Significant Bit or LSB) is set to 1, irrespective of the other bits in @TablesToCheck.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-and-operator-amp?view=vs-2019

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you.

Comment: Aside: Another common way to check an integer for odd values is using the [modulus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operator: `if ( @TablesToCheck % 2 = 1)`. Note that negative values have negative remainders, e.g. `-7 % 2` is `-1`, not `1`. This can be handled either by taking the absolute value (`abs`) or check for a non-zero remainder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The & (Bitwise AND) operator compares the binary representation of the two inputs, and returns only the bits that are set to 1 on both sides.

In this case it will return 1 if the first bit in @TablesToCheck is set to 1, and 0 if the first bit in @TablesToCheck is set to 0.

```
0000 0001 = 1
0000 0010 = 2
---------
0000 0000 = 0

0000 0001 = 1
0000 0011 = 3
---------
0000 0001 = 1
```

The end results is that the IF statement will evaluate as true when @TablesToCheck is an odd number, and false if it is even or zero.